# Can you run Sweave in a new environment?

Tags: r, sweave

I am writing a package that works with Sweave and would like to be able to sandbox the Sweave call from the global environment. This is how I would think it should work but doesn't:

```
sweaveEnv <- new.env()
eval(Sweave('myDocument.Rnw'), envir=sweaveEnv)
```

Ideally I would then like to save that environment for later debugging.

```
save(sweaveEnv, file='mySweaveEnv.Rda')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply start a new R process:

```
system("Rscript -e 'Sweave(\"test.Rnw\");save.image(file=\"mySweaveEnv.Rda\")'")
```

Answer (score 3):

If your main purpose is to save the objects in that environment, you can use the `knitr` package with the chunk option `cache=TRUE`, in which case all the objects in a chunk are saved in files, and you can load them into R later for debugging; `knitr` will create a `.rdx` and `.rdb` file respectively for a chunk under the cache directory, and you can call `lazyLoad()` to load the objects in these databases into R.

If you want to do more things with the environment in which the chunk is evaluated, `knitr` also has [chunk hooks](http://yihui.github.com/knitr/hooks) and you have access to the environments via hooks; so basically you can do whatever you want -- `knitr` makes almost everything open to the user. Note each chunk is evaluated in a different empty environment when cache is on. I do not have examples on this topic yet, so please let me know if my description here is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks Yihui. I intend to add support for knitr and cacheSweave for the package I am developing and may hit you up for your help in the next week or so.